# What is wrong with my solution to this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

> The base $ABCD$ of the figure has area $9$. The point $M$ divides the segment $AB$ on ratio $2$ and the edge $BF$ of length $2$ forms an angle of $60º$. Calculate $[CM,CB,BF]$, knowing that $\mathbb{V}^3$ is oriented by a positive basis.
>
> [image]

I did the following:

- I assumed $CB=(3,0,0)$.
- To find the coordinates of $CM$: The $x$ coordinate seems to be $3$ too and the $y$ coordinate seems to be $\frac{3}{2}$, as it's a point in the plane, the $z$ coordinate is $0$, hence: $CM=(3,\frac{3}{2},0)$
- Now to find the coordinates of $BF$, the $x$ coordinate seems to be also $3$, to obtain the $y$ coordinate, I've imagined a line starting on $F$, parallel to $GP$, then I'd have a triangle $BFP'$. As the angle $FBP'=60º=\frac{\pi}{3}$, I found the length $BP'$ doing the following:

  - The slope of $BF$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, then I can think about a function $f(x)=\frac{\pi x}{3}$, I guess that $BP'$ can be found taking the distance from $(0,0)$ to $(x,\frac{\pi x}{3})$ such that this distance is equal to $2$ and hence:
  - $$\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{\pi^2 x^2}{9}}=2 \\ x^2 + \frac{\pi^2 x^2}{9} = 4 \\ x=\pm  \frac{6}{\sqrt{9+\pi^2}}$$
  - Then if the $y$ coordinate of $CM$ is positive and the $y$ coordinate of $CB$ is zero, then the $y$ coordinate of $BP'$ must be negative.
  - Now to obtain the $z$ coordinate. I know that $x=3, y= -\frac{6}{\sqrt{9+\pi^2}}$, then:
  - $$a^2+\left(-\frac{6}{\sqrt{9+\pi^2}}\right)^2=2^2 \\ a=\pm \frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{9+\pi ^2}}$$
  - And hence: $BF=\left(3,-\frac{6}{\sqrt{9+\pi^2}},\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{9+\pi ^2}}\right)$
- Finally: $$
  \begin{vmatrix}
   3 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
   3 & 0 & 0 \\
   3 & -\frac{6}{\sqrt{9+\pi ^2}} & \frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{9+\pi ^2}} \\
  \end{vmatrix}=-\frac{9 \pi }{\sqrt{9+\pi ^2}}
  $$
- As the basis is positive, it should be: $$\frac{9 \pi }{\sqrt{9+\pi ^2}}$$.

The problem is that this result does not match with the answers given by the book. What have I done wrong?

Comment: To start with, a segment is not a point. First you need to specify the axis you use! In any case using your terminology and assumption, I believe that CM becomes - (2,-3,0)

Comment: @JesusChrist : "The slope of $BF$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, then I can think about a function $f(x)=\frac{\pi x}{3}$" didn't you confuse the angle with its $\tan$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Perhaps yes, I'll try to so it with the tangent of the angle.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I tried it. I guess I was really confusing and interpreting the angle as it's tangent. I corrected it now, but I still don't know what is wrong. This time, the result of the determinant was $9$.

Comment: "The point $M$ divides the segment $AB$ on ratio $2$" is $2$ $\frac{AM}{MB}$ or $\frac{BM}{MA}$ or $\frac{AM}{AB}$ ? Then, to clarify too, is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ angle between plane $ABC$ and $BF$? Knowing that all, I'd prefer to post another approach as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin That is also acceptable. As my approach seems to not work. I just posted it here to show that I tried to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll denote $[a\times b]$ or $[a,b]$ the cross product; $(a,b)$ or $a\cdot b$ the dot product and $(a,b,c)=[a\times b]\cdot c$.
We're asked to find $$(CM,CB,BF)=[CM\times CB]\cdot BF=[CB+BM\times CB]\cdot BF=
([CB\times CB]+[BM\times CB],BF)=(0+[BM\times CB],BF)$$
Now, I'd suppose "The point $M$ divides the segment $AB$ on ratio 2" is $\frac{AM}{MB}=2$, as may be seen from the diagram, so $BM=\frac{1}{3}BA$. Then,
$$(CM,CB,BF)=([BM\times CB],BF)=([\frac{1}{3}BA\times CB],BF)=\frac{1}{3}([BA,CB],BF)=\frac{1}{3}(-[BA,BC],BF)=\frac{1}{3}([BC,BA],BF)=
\frac{1}{3}|[BC,BA]|\cdot |BF|\cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{3}$$
Briefly, why $\sin \frac{\pi}{3}$ : $[BC,BA]$ is the vector with length of $\operatorname{Area}(ABCD)$, orthogonal to plane $ABC$ and pointing upwards or downwards. To determine, upwards or downwards we use that rule:"Direction of $[a\times b]$ is selected such, that the shortest turn from $a$ to $b$, viewed from end of $[a\times b]$ would be counterclockwise" in a positive basis.
The shortest turn from $BC$ to $BA$ is counterclockwise, when viewed from from above of the plane $ABC$, so the vector $[BC\times BA]$ points upwards.
$([BC,BA],BF)=|[BC,BA]|\cdot |BF|\cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $[BC,BA]$ and $BF$, but $\theta+$given $\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $\cos \theta = \sin \frac{\pi}{3}$.
Finally, $$(CM,CB,BF)=\frac{1}{3}|[BC,BA]|\cdot |BF|\cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{3} = 
\frac{1}{3}\cdot 9\cdot 2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=3\sqrt{3}\hbox{.}$$

Comment: One doubt. Why $BM=1/3BA$? Isn't the point $M$ in the middle of $BA$?

Comment: (Oh, your answer is the same given by my book. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm just asking for clarification).

Comment: I believe "The point $M$ divides the segment $AB$ on ratio $2$" is meant to be "The point $M$ divides the segment $AB$ on ratio $2:1$", i.e. $\frac{AM}{MB}=2$. Anyway, if $BM=1/2BA$, the resulting answer would be $\frac{3}{2}$ times larger, i.e. the ratio $\frac{BM}{BA}$ doesn't affect the solution much, but only the answer. :)

Comment: I guess this changes everything I tried to do. Later, I'll try to use my methods again and see if it works with this new ratio.